# After running :make in Vim, vim will jump to nonsenical files

Tags: vim, makefile

Sometimes I'll have an error in a file and the output from `:make` is something like this:

```
In file included from /path/to/some/src/file.cpp|22| 0:
```

And so when it jumps to that file, it doesn't jump to file.cpp, it jumps to the file named `In file included from /path/to/some/src/file.cpp`, which is clearly nonsensical. In general I like the jumping, just not when the error is of that form causing me to have useless files open instead of the real error I care about

Is there a way to make it smarter so that it jumps to the real error, which is on the next line, or at very least, only jump if the thing it finds is a real file?

Comment: I think that's just due to the output from the compiler and vim will simply parse that output as an error line. Vim can't tell the difference between an error generated via a #include dependency or another type of C/C++ error. I'd suspsect you'd have to define your own custom error processing to deal with those specific #include  errors where you want to ignore the file that is #included.

Comment: I figured that much, but bewteen the thousands of people who use vim and people the who program in c or c++, I figure someone out there must have figured out a way to make this a little cleaner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to modify the `errorformat` setting. See `:help 'errorformat'` and `:help errorformat`. To know the current value you can run `:set errorformat?`.